# How is typesetting in multiple columns implemented

Tags: two-column

I can type

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
```

to get a document typeset in two columns. But how does this works internally? I read *The TeXbook*, but didn't find a single paragraph about this. (Maybe I didn't look carefully enough.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The routine is described by Knuth in Appendix E: Example Formats, page 417. The macros were  used for two-column  formatting of Appendix I, the  index.

The algorithm is not to difficult to follow. Everything is placed in a tall box of a width equal to the column width and then split. For a page that is full this simple algorithm works quite well. The only complication is when one needs to balance the columns in a page when there is not enough content. Here Knuth uses a loop to achieve it.

The `\begindoublecolumns` macro  operates by  first saving the  current `\box255` 
in  `\partialpage`.

It then changes the   output  routine  to  `\doublecolumnout`,  changing `\hsize`  to `\colwidth`, and changing `\vsize`   to `\bigcolheight`. The last one is a  bit more than  twice the original `\vsize`.

This allows a very tall column to  accumulate. When `\doublecolumnout`  is called, `\vsplit`   is  used  to extract  columns of  the  correct height.

When  `\enddoublecolumns`  occurs, the  output routine  `\balancecolumns`  uses  a  `\loop`  in  an  attempt to  split the current `\box255`  into two columns of  equal height.

Then  `\pagesofar`   packages  these boxes side by  side and contributes the  result  (along with  the   `\partialpage`,   if  any)  to   the   current vertical list, and normal processing resumes.

Knuth writes,

> A more difficult approach would be
>   necessary if the index contained
>   insertions (e.g., footnotes);
>   fortunately, it doesn't.

Unfortunately most do and they include floating figures and tables! The LaTeX Team took extra care to provide a highly complicated two-column algorithm to cater for all these, albeit still in not such a perfect way.

Answer (score 9):

ConTeXt supports two types of multi-column output: simple multi-columns (similar to LaTeX's twocolumn) and column-sets (much more control over spanning figures, etc.). The source code for [simple multi-columns](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/tex/context/base/mkii/page-mul.mkii) gives a lot of implementation details and history; the source code for [column sets](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/tex/context/base/mkii/page-set.mkii) has a few comments about the implementation.